# Paypal notify_url being misintepreted

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm having a problem where my notify_url parameter is getting mis-intepreted by  paypal. Its basically changeing "http://" to "http:/"

Here's my code, c#.net

```
string payPalParams = "";
        payPalParams = "&cmd=_xclick";
        payPalParams += "&business=xxx@example.com";
        payPalParams += "&item_name=xxx";
        payPalParams += "&item_number=xxx";
        payPalParams += "&currency_code=GBP";
        payPalParams += "&amount=0.01";
        payPalParams += "&notify_url=http://example.com/IPN/UpdateTheDB";
        payPalParams += "&cancel_return=http://example.com/cancel";
        payPalParams += "&return=http://example.com/thankyou";
        Response.Redirect("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" + payPalParams);
```

I've checked under debug what I've sent is correct and when I look at the paypal IPN history page, the notify url is missing a slash and so fails. see below.

```
Message ID    5J8852596V365361T
Date/time created    05/12/2015 23:55 GMT
Original/Resent    Original
Latest delivery attempt date/time    06/12/2015 00:16 GMT
Notification URL    **http:/example.com/IPN/UpdateTheDB**
HTTP response code
Delivery status    Retrying
No. of retries 8
Transaction ID 1VB33352R5501751J
IPN type Transaction made
```

Has anyone see this problem.

Comment: `1VB33352R5501751J` this does not look like a valid transaction id for live paypal account

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'd changed the tx ids for this post, wasn't sure if it was best to show it.

Comment: please create a ticket at https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/